# Pre-configured Python web framework with Authentication, Profiles, etc

Tags: python

I want port some my Python scripts into web apps so that others can use it and I'll use some sort of web framework. I've been playing around with Django lately but it doesn't have the basic user registration, email verification stuff built in and one would probably end up using `django-registration`.
Almost all web applications require you to create an account, verify your account by clicking that verification link in your account and so on. One would save a lot of time if he could just skip past the part of setting up authentication, verification, the usual log-in and log-out pages and get to part of doing the "core" part.
Has anyone come across a pre-configured Python web-framework (Django would be nice) that does the all usual basic stuff? Django has that `contrib.auth` bit you can add `django-registration`

(I hope this question sounds reasonable.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Pinax ( http://pinaxproject.com/ ), which consists of a set of Django apps that take care of some of the most common tasks. Including the user registration one you outlined.

However, this is actually not very difficult to build. You are right, most sides need it, but implementing it even from scratch is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

web2py take a look at Access Control Chapter in http://web2py.com/book